# Tasking : Run a set of actions every x minutes

Tags: jakarta-ee, twitter, scheduled-tasks

I have to deal with rate limits in **Twitter API**.

I choose to use task in order to not get blocked.

I was wondering is there're any ways to **perform a set of actions (call different methods) every x minutes** ?

For example, I can make 80 requests every 15 minutes. Let's supposed that I have to call methods a() and b() ; respectively 120 times and 80 times.

I would have to task :

a() to get called : 80 times
... waiting 15 minutes
a() to get called : 40 times
b() to get called : 40 times
... waiting 15 minutes
b() to get called : 40 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with Java EE Conccurency Utilities [ManagedScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedScheduledExecutorService.html) API.

You have two methods that would work for your use case:

1. `scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable r, long initDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)`
2. `scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable r, long initDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)`

The only difference between these two is `scheduleAtFixedRate` will run every `period` TimeUnit's.  Whereas `scheduleWithFixedDelay` will run `period` TimeUnit's **after** the previous execution has completed.  So, if your task runs very quickly then these two methods are essentially the same.

*Note:* This API was introduced in Java EE 7.  If you are running on EE 6 or lower, use Java SE's [ScheduledExecuorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html?is-external=true) instead.

**To obtain an instance in a Java EE environment:**
Inject it:

```
@Resource
ManagedScheduledExecutorService scheduledExec;
```

Or lookup:

```
ManagedScheduledExecutorService scheduledExec = 
    (ManagedScheduledExecutorService) new InitialContext.lookup(
        "java:comp/DefaultManagedScheduledExecutorService");
```

**To use it:**

```
// Sample runnables
// Call a() 80 times
Runnable a = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
            a();
    }
};
// Call b() 120 times
Runnable b = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
            b();
    }
};

// Submit and run.  Will repeat every 15 minutes until cancelled
scheduledExec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(a, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
scheduledExec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(b, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

// scheduleWithFixedDelay also returns a ScheduledFuture,
// which can be used to monitor and cancel your tasks
ScheduledFuture<?> future = managedExec.scheduleWithFixedDelay(...);
future.cancel(true);
```

Comment: It seems to be exactly what I am looking for ! Thank you :)

Comment: @Dinath you're welcome! please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry, I am new here ! Done :) see you